# Select statement, table sample, equal distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's assume there is a SQL Server 2008 table like below, that holds 10 million rows. 
One of the fields is Id, since it's identity it is from 1 to 10 million.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stats
(
   id      INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   field1  INT,
   field2  INT,
   ...
)
```

Is there an efficient way by doing one select statement to get a subset of this data that satisfies the following requirements:

- contains a limited number of rows in the result set, i.e. 100, 200, etc.
- provides equal distribution of a certain column, not random, i.e. of column id

So, in our example, if we return 100 rows, the result set would look like this:

```
Row 1 - 100 000
Row 2 - 200 000
Row 3 - 300 000
...
Row 100 - 10 000 000
```

I want to avoid using cursor and storing this in a separate table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how *efficient* it's going to be, but thie following query will return every 100000th row (relative to ordering established by `id`):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN
    FROM Stats
) T
WHERE RN % 100000 = 0
ORDER BY id
```

Since it does not rely on actual `id` values, this will work even if you have "holes" in the sequence of `id` values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT id FROM dbo..Stats WHERE id % 100000 = 0
```

it should work, since you are saying that id goes from 1 to 10 000 000. If number of rows is not known, but number of resulting rows is what you know, then just calculate that 100000 number like (if you would like 100 resulting rows):

```
SELECT id FROM Stats WHERE (id % (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Stats) / 100) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you pointed me to the right direction, I would mark both yours and Branko's as answers!